# Non-GPL ADO.NET provider for MySQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql, ado.net

Is there any NON-GPL ADO.NET provider for MySQL ?

There is the official one from here
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net
but unfortunately, it's under the GPL, not the LGPL.

I am developing an abstract class for database access.
I don't care whether the abstraction layer is going to be GPL, 
but if it uses MySQL (I mean the MySQL ADO.NET provider, not the MySQL database itselfs) it will be GPL, and thus, any application that uses that layer, which is something I don't want...


Oh, and I know about nHibernate/Subsonic/otherORMs, but it doesn't fit my needs.

ADO.NET provider short of using ODBC of course.

**Edit/Clarification:** 
Note that by "abstract class for database access", I don't mean write my own universal ADO.NET provider.
I mean writing a wrapper class around a set of already existing ADO.NET providers.

Comment: using the connector doesn't force you to opensource that code, it's only if you added a feature to the connector that you have to then opensource that connector.

Comment: @ Joseph Le Brech: But that would be LGPL, GPL is different...

Comment: If you are worried about it just abstract it in your .cs file. LGPL is for staticly linked libraries. but you would be dynamically linking and not adding any new features to the connector. If you are truly worried then use sql server.

Comment: Your use of a data adapter could be interpreted as aggregation, please read http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the perfect answer:

One can use `System.Data.Odbc` to get around it.
You can always say, it's generic ODBC, has nothing in particular to do with MySQL, easily replacable.
And whatever you put in the connection string is the problem of your customers.
If the SQL that you send over the ODBC connection works in MySQL/MariaDB only, that's regrettable - but no legal problem ;)

**Edit - 2016 Update:**
You can use the MIT-licensed MySqlConnector for .NET Core (which also works for .NET)
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector

Comment: Are there any resources I can read to use ODBC with MariaDB? Currently I'm developing an application and I want to avoid having licensing issues.

Answer (score 3):

There is DevArt's ADO.NET provider for MySQL

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

Comment: I should have added free as in "no royalties" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stop swallowing the Microsoft FUD.

This is covered by v2 of the GPL therefore, unless you intend to modify the supplied code and redistribute it (as opposed to bundling it with your own application) your only constrained in that you need to state that the bundle includes GPL v2.0 licensed code and reference the copyright owner (which you are nearly always required to do with most commercially licensed software anyway).

Comment: There is some argument about whether dynamic linking comprises of a combined work, which the FSF says it is whilst other lawers says it isn't, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1717509/35233 so it can be a bit hazy, and that uncertainty is coming from the FSF.

Comment: @symcbean: Certainly not. Else I would be possible to pack GPL programs into a dll, modify some function on top in the library on top of the GPL library and sell it. On top of that, there would be no reason for the LGPL to exist...

Comment: @Quandary: which is exactly what lots of vendors already legitimately do.

Comment: @symcbean: If they do and the library is GPL and not LGPL, then it's illegal AFAIK (though as those examples show, one can do it illegally), unless they communicate with GPL v2 licensed code via network, or they don't distribute the software, in which case the entire discussion is pointless anyway.

Comment: It seems pretty clear here: https://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php


At the bottom:  

This General Public License does not permit incorporating your program into proprietary programs. If your program is a subroutine library, you may consider it more useful to permit linking proprietary applications with the library. If this is what you want to do, use the GNU Library General Public License instead of this License.

Answer (score 0):

> but if it uses MySQL it will be GPL

Ah - no. You can program it ina  way it does not even KNOW it connects to MySql.

- Isolate all abstractions into a separate assembly.
- Implement your propietary interfaces in this (allowed).
- Distribute the abstraction of mySql as gpl.

Finished.

Comment: No it won't. Only if it uses MySQL sourcecode, which is unlikely for a C# library. MySQL will remain GPL and you'll still need to get a MySQL license, but only if you use MySQL, not just when you incorporate the driver. If it was GPL v3, then it would be true, but it's GPL v2.

Comment: Read what I say again, You mixed it up - totally.

Comment: I think I got what you meant by now. NO ! I was not talking about MySQL. Read carefully: I was talking about the "MySQL ADO.NET Provider", and when I write "MySQL" it refers to "the MySQL ADO.NET provider" which is GPL as well... I was not talking about writing my own ADO.NET provider, I am talking about using those ADO.NET providers. I certainly don't intend to write an entire ADO.NET provider. I simply build a wrapper class around each ADO.NET provider.